# Automated Magento block creation whith bash

Tags: magento, sh

Does anyone know if there a bash script to **create a Magento block** in an automated way?

I already looked a little on github but I haven't found anything.

Thank you

Comment: You should change your tag from [sh] to [bash]. And have to include a small but representative sample of what a magneto block is in order for non-magento experts to help. If a mag-block is a mix of config parameters and variable values, you can probably do `printf "opt1 $var1\nopt2 $var2 ..."` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extensions and tools for creating module frameworks - for example [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-module-creator.html) and [this](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/).  I'm not aware of one for creating blocks, specifically, but blocks are part of the module's created with these tools.